# Driving an LED from a switch

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga

I have been studying Verilog with Altera's Quartus II in combination with the terASIC DE10 board, but now something unexpected is happening.

For the sake of debugging, I am driving an LED through a switch, and between the two, I have inserted a module:
[switch-module-led](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSyTh.png)

The module code is as below, where the value of the variable `to_led` is updated every time `in_clock_counter[0]` change.

```
module in_out (
                input [31:0] in_clock_counter,
                input from_switch,
                output reg to_led
    );



always @ (posedge in_clock_counter)
    begin
        if (from_switch)
            to_led <= 1'b1;
        else
            to_led <= 1'b0;
    end 

endmodule
```

I would expect that if I press the switch, the LED would be lit. But, this is not the case.
Using Simulation Waveform Editor I can see that the LED value changes.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Start with checking 1/ If you  pin assignments are correct. 2/ If still not working. remove the clock, just switch to output (This is in case your assumed clock is not present)

Comment: Hi @Oldfart, thank you very much for helping me again. 
The LED is assigned to the correct pin: I double checked it, but it was worth a try.
If I write a simple 'assign to_led = from_switch' the LED actually turns on when the key is pressed. What I am aiming to do is to set the output through an if statement, so simply assigning the input value to the output is not enough. Might it be because both are _wire_ type?

Comment: Another approach I tried was to have a reg variable in the if statement and then assigning the reg variable to the output. This did not work either.

I am finding confusing that the simulation actually shows the desired output, but the board does not.

I have so much to learn!

Comment: OK, I **am** getting old: I completely missed that the clock comes in as a vector (as pointed out be Justin N). Make that a single bit and your chance of success goes up by 3100% Also follow Justin's advice: do NOT use derived clocks.

Comment: Hi @Oldfart, I understand your worries about a vector used as a clock and I concur: the compiler gave me some warnings about it. 
I connected the clock that is coming out a PLL block, with no success. I was using the PLL block to have a lower frequency rate, ten times less than the original clock one.
Then I connected the clock straight from the CLOCK_50 pin, which is the system clock and the system works as intended.
I am a bit confused: isn't it a PLL block necessary to create a constant clock frequency? I thought so. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and the system works as intended

Happy you got it working.

> isn't it a PLL block necessary to create a constant clock frequency? I thought so.

No, the best, most stable clock is the one that come straight from your oscillator.
The PLL allows you to make different frequencies from that clock (other then the usual: divide-by-2, divide-by-3 etc.)

For example, some allow you to make something as weird as a 23/3 times clock. Thus also a higher frequency.  (In fact that is where the 3GHz processors get their clock from.) But the jitter specs will always be worse then your crystal.

But still that code should work from the PLL clock so I suspect something else is still wrong. I suggest you have a look at the synthesized netlist (schematic). And check what is all connected where.

Answer (score 1):

You could be confusing the tool by passing a multi-bit vector to a `posedge` sensitivity list. It's a pretty unusual thing to do, so I wouldn't trust the synthesis toolchain with something like that.

There are also other complications with using logic outputs as clock signals in an FPGA. It's not likely to be your immediate problem because your module is trivial, but may cause you problems down the road. You should consider using a normal clock signal there, and creating logic to check the value of the counter.

Also consider that if this module works in simulation, maybe the bug is not in this module.

Comment: Hi @Justin, thanks for your contribution.
I had a warning on the compiler saying that the posedge would have been timed on the first bit of the 32 bit counter. I thought it was something that could have been done but I'm happy to amend.
Connecting the input for the posedge to the output of a PLL didn't work.
Connecting the input for the posedge of the FPGA reference clock CLOCK_50 did the trick. Which is puzzling for me, as the block is very simple and what I want to achieve is almost banal.